# The current user's settings are not being saved prior to the logout occurring

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, logout

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this annoying bug I am having.

In my app, when the user logs out, I want to be able to change the user's property of "shareLocation" to false before that occurs.

However, it's not updating correctly.

I noticed however, when no `PFUser.logOut()` function call is made, the user's property will then update properly on the backend.

I also noticed that there are two different logout methods: `logOutinBackground` and `logOutInBackgroundWithBlock`

So I'm assuming that `PFUser.logOut()`'s execution happens before the save to background call?

Could someone help me find out the proper implementation of this?

Thank you in advance!

Relevant code snippets below. Please let me know if more info is needed.

PS - I also tried having the `PFUser.logOut()` come immediately after the `user!.saveInBackground()` call, in addition to the **prepareForSegue** method below, and the user was still not updating correctly prior to the logout and segue getting called.

```
@IBAction func btnLogout(sender: AnyObject) {

    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user!["shareLocation"] = false
    user!.saveInBackground()

    performSegueWithIdentifier("logoutSegue", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "logoutSegue") {
        PFUser.logOut()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save in background with a completion block, then, in the completion block trigger the logout request. In this way you know that the new status is saved and that you can safely logout. You can also check the status to be sure the save worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
user!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if success {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("logoutSegue", sender: self)
    } else {
        NSLog("%@", error)
    }
}
```

---

Because before the `saveInBackground()` is finished you're logging out the user.